# object_usage_linter marks wrong line with no visible binding message

Tags: r, static-analysis, lintr

Consider the following code snippet (comments at the end indicate line numbers and are **not** part of the problem):

```r
set.seed(1)                                   # 1
my_dat1 <- data.frame(x = runif(100, 1, 10),  # 2
                      w = runif(100, 1, 10))  # 3
                                              # 4
my_dat1$y_orig <- my_dat1$x * my_dat1$w       # 5
my_dat1$y_obs  <- my_dat1$y_orig + rnorm(100) # 6
                                              # 7
my_stat <- function(data, orig_mod) {         # 8
  new_mod <- update(orig_mod, data = data)    # 9
  r <- residuals(new_mod)                     #10
  f <- fitted(new_mod)                        #11
  l <- lowess(f, r)                           #12
  res <- c(l$x, l$y)                          #13
  res                                         #14
}                                             #15
```

When I `lint` this file via  `lintr:::addin_lint()` I get the following strange error:

> ```
> $ test.R:List of 8
>  ..$ filename     : chr "test.R
>  ..$ line_number  : int 6
>  ..$ column_number: int 14
>  ..$ type         : chr "warning"
>  ..$ message      : chr "no visible binding for global variable ‘x’"
>  ..$ line         : chr "  res <- c(l$x, l$y)                          #13"
>  ..$ ranges       :List of 1
>  .. ..$ : int [1:2] 14 14
>  ..$ linter       : chr "object_usage_linter"
>  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lint"
> $ test.R:List of 8
>  ..$ filename     : chr "test.R"
>  ..$ line_number  : int 6
>  ..$ column_number: int 19
>  ..$ type         : chr "warning"
>  ..$ message      : chr "no visible binding for global variable ‘y’"
>  ..$ line         : chr "  res <- c(l$x, l$y)                          #13"
>  ..$ ranges       :List of 1
>  .. ..$ : int [1:2] 19 19
>  ..$ linter       : chr "object_usage_linter"
>  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lint"
> - attr(*, "class")= chr "lints"
> ```

However, if I **remove** lines `#5` and `#6` I do not have the error any more:

```r
set.seed(1)                                   # 1
my_dat1 <- data.frame(x = runif(100, 1, 10),  # 2
                      w = runif(100, 1, 10))  # 3
                                              # 4
                                              # 7
my_stat <- function(data, orig_mod) {         # 8
  new_mod <- update(orig_mod, data = data)    # 9
  r <- residuals(new_mod)                     #10
  f <- fitted(new_mod)                        #11
  l <- lowess(f, r)                           #12
  res <- c(l$x, l$y)                          #13
  res                                         #14
}                                             #15
```

There is **no** error when linting this file.

**Questions**

1. Is this an intentional behaviour or is a bug in `lintr`?
2. Why is the line number wrong given that `lintr` complains about a snippet in line number `#13` and not in line number `#6`?